# How to pass value to popup window using codeigniter?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I know that you can use anchor_popup() to open up a new window in codeigniter, but what i cant figure out is how to pass values using that.

Here is the code i am using,

```
$attr = array('width'=>'800','height'=>'700');
echo anchor_popup('friends/'.$uid.'/'.$suid.'','add as friend',$attr);
```

Now i get a popup window which links to friends/34/34 where friends is a controller and rest are values which i want to give to my controller. but iam getting an error 404,

404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
I am using uri segment to grab the values.

Could any tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the link `friends/34/34/` is looking for a controller called "friends" and a method called "34", hence why it can't be found.

If your `friends` controller has no other methods, then change the link to this:

`echo anchor_popup('friends/index/'.$uid.'/'.$suid,'add as friend',$attr);`

else, add the appropriate method.